# Dereference void pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Even after casting a void pointer, I am getting compilation error while dereferencing it.
Could anyone please let me know the reason of this.

```
int lVNum = 2;
void *lVptr;
lVptr = (int*)&lVNum;

printf("\nlVptr[60 ] is  %d \n",lVptr[1]);
```

Comment: You can't dereference a void pointer. What's the actual compilation error?

Comment: In four lines of code we have (a) an unnecessary cast, (b) an illegal dereference of an untyped pointer, and (c) out-of-bounds undefined-behaviour.

Comment: What compiler errors do you get? It's difficult to tell you the reason for errors without the actual errors themselves.

Comment: @Code-Guru: In general, yes.  Here, not so much.

Comment: What do you expect `lVptr[1]` to return?

Comment: If you were trying to inspect the second byte of the `int`, you could use a `%c` format specifier and cast the int to a `(char *)`.

Comment: `lVptr[1]` doesn't _return_ anything, it's a dereference, not a function!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`printf("\nlVptr[60 ] is  %d \n", *(int*)lVptr);`

This will cast the void pointer to a pointer to an `int` and then dereference it correctly.

If you want to treat it as an array (of one), you could do a slightly ugly `((int *)lVptr)[0]`. Using `[1]` is out of bounds, and therefore not a good idea (as for `lVptr[60]`...)

Answer (score 48):

It doesn't make sense to dereference a void pointer.  How will the compiler interpret the memory that the pointer is pointing to?  You need to cast the pointer to a proper type first:

```
int x = *(int*)lVptr;
```

Comment: Why does the compiler have to care about interpreting memory? Isn't that up to the operations I manipulate that memory with?

Comment: To manipulate memory you have to use operators like `+` and the behavior of those operators depends on what integer types are on either side.  Or even just to read some memory, you need to specify a type so the compiler knows how many bytes to read. If you want free form access to memory, cast the pointer to a `uint8_t *`.

Answer (score 7):

You can not dereference a **void** pointer because it doesn't have a type,
first you need to cast it`(int *)lVptr`, then dereference it `*(int *)lVptr`.

```
int lVNum = 2;
void *lVptr;
lVptr = &lVNum;

printf("\nlVptr[60 ] is  %d \n",*(int *)lVptr);
```

Answer (score 6):

It's still a `void*` because that's what you declared it as.  Any pointer may be implicitly converted to a `void*`, so that cast does nothing and you are left with a pointer to `void` just as you began with.

You'll need to declare it as an `int*`.

```
void *some_ptr = /* whatever */;
int *p = (int*)some_ptr;
// now you have a pointer to int cast from a pointer to void
```

Note that the cast *to* an `int*` is also unnecessary, for the same reason you don't have to (and should *not*) cast the return value of `malloc` in C.

`void*`'s can be implicitly converted to and from any other pointer type.  I added the cast here only for clarity, in your code you would simply write;

```
int *p = some_void_ptr;
```

---

Also, this:

```
lVptr[1]
```

Is wrong.  You have a pointer to a single `int`, not two.  That dereference causes undefined behavior.

Comment: +1 the only thing left in this is the cast, which in C isn't needed. Other than that, this addresses it all.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yeah, I just wanted it to be as clear as possible.  I suppose I should mention it though; it may prevent silly `malloc` casts in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Example of what you might be trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    void *v;
    unsigned long int *i = (unsigned long int *)v;

    *i = 5933016743776703571;

    size_t j = sizeof(i);
    printf("There are %ld bytes in v\n", j);

    size_t k;
    for (k = 0; k < j; k++) {
        printf("Byte %ld of v: %c\n", k, ((char *)v)[k]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
There are 8 bytes in v
Byte 0 of v: S
Byte 1 of v: T
Byte 2 of v: A
Byte 3 of v: C
Byte 4 of v: K
Byte 5 of v: O
Byte 6 of v: V
Byte 7 of v: R
```

Answer (score 1):

A void pointer is just that, a pointer to a void (nothing definable).

Useful in some instances.
For example malloc() returns a void pointer precisely because it allocated memory for an UNDEFINED purpose.
Some functions may likewise take void pointers as arguments because they don't care about the actual content other than a location.

To be honest, the snippet you posted makes absolutely no sense, can't even guess what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

@ Code-Guru
 I tried to compile it in visual studio. It gives error - expression must be a pointer to complete object.

Thanks teppic,
As you suggested, the following compiles and yields right result.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){

printf("study void pointers \n");

int lvnum = 2;
void *lvptr;
lvptr = &lvnum;
printf("\n lvptr is %d\n",((int *)lvptr)[0]);


}
```

However if I try printf("\n lvptr is %d\n",((int *)lVptr)[60]);
It compiles and runs but gives random number.

Thanks a lot, friends for all the suggestions. Apologies that I assigned a void pointer to unnecessarily casted int pointer and expected it to get dereferenced. However I should have casted it when I want to dereference it.

Purpose of the snippet:
In my sources I found klocwork error which was caused by similar situation. On the contrary the program not only compiled but also gave correct results. Reason- it is a low level code (no OS) where the memory assigned to the void pointer is already reserved till the count of like 60. But the klocwork tool was unable to parse the files having that limit resulting in error. I did a lot of brain storming and ended up in something silly.

Saurabh