# Can we dereference a void pointer without knowing its type?

Tags: c

I have a question regarding the void pointer in c language. I would like to know Can we dereference a **void pointer** without knowing its **type**?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468441/dereference-void-pointer

Comment: @haccks: It's not merely undefined behavior, it's a constraint violation.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 3):

No, because you don't know how to **interpret** the data contained by the corresponding memory space. Memory itself has no type, and it is pointers that contains the type information. For example, memory pointed to by `int *` is interpreted as an `int`.

When dereferencing a `void *`, there is no way for the compiler to tell which type bytes starting from that address should be interpreted as. It can be a `double`, an `unsigned long`, or even an array of `char`s.

However, it is possible to get dereference a `void *` through casting, because the cast operator contains the information about object type.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** No, you can't.

While dereferencing a *pointer-to-type*, you generate an "object" of the *type*.

Since a `void` is not a complete type, you cannot dereference a `void*` directly. That is why, you need to either

- copy the pointer to another pointer of a complete type
- cast the pointer to another complete type

and then, you can dereference to get the object of the *new* complete type.

Comment: What does *TL;DR* mean?

Comment: @EdHeal What? Don't tell me you don't know this. :)

Comment: If I knew I would not ask the question

Comment: @EdHeal I'm not sure whether you're kidding me or not, but it's very common in SO (I learnt it from here). It stands for Too long din't read (summary). For someone having an extensive presence like you, i'm surprised you are seeing this new. :)

Comment: The coffee has not kicked in yet :-(

Answer (score 1):

No, A **void pointer** can be dereferenced only after explicit casting. For example:

```
int a = 5;
void *b = &a;
printf(“%d\n”, *((int*)b));
```

Comment: Right, but after the cast, technically, _without knowing its type_ is not applicable anymore. :)

Comment: You can take a void pointer which you don't know the type of, cast it to int* and then dereference it. So technically you can. But why on earth someone would want to, I don't know.

Comment: @Magisch; `char *a = "s"; void *x = s; char c = *(int *)x;`, is this correct?

Comment: @haccks When in doubt, try it

Comment: @Magisch I think that was a rhetorical q.

Comment: @Magisch; I know it's wrong. Asking your opinion as what you said in your first comment: *You can take a void pointer which you don't know the type of, cast it to `int*` and then dereference it. So technically you can*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Dereferencing a void pointer requires an explicit cast beforehand.

You can ofcourse cast it to any particular type and then dereference it without knowing its original type, but why you would want to do that is beyond me.