# Passing C++ void pointers

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I'm confused about void pointers. Although this code fragment compiles, is dereferencing variable c in function f2 undefined behaviour?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

void f2(void* c) {  // legal/stupid
    // although this compiles, is dereferencing c here undefined behaviour?
}

void f1(void** b) {
    printf("%d\n", *(int*)*b);
    f2(b);
}

int main() {    
    int i{ 5 };
    void* a{ (void*)&i };
    f1(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for initializing your variables with curly braces? Also, it would be nice to include in the question the reason for which you think this code invokes UB... :)

Comment: You can't dereference a void pointer.

Comment: Unless you have to work with C API's, I'd suggest you stay away from void pointers.  C++ has a very good type system and templates replace the need for void pointers.

Comment: @NeilButterworth is [right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468441/dereference-void-pointer), but I think OP didn't not mean to ask that.. I guess.. :)

Comment: @NeilButterworth The OP isn't.  A `void**` is not a `void*`, it is a pointer to a `void*` and you can dereference that, as it yields a `void*`.

Comment: @Nathan I was responding to the comment `// although this compiles, is dereferencing c here undefined behaviour?` As `c` is a void pointer, you cannot dereference it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Oh, OK.  Missed the comment.

Comment: _@sid_ Any reasoning why you're messing around with raw pointers in c++?

Comment: Note that `void**` arguments in C APIs are only used for output parameters that are pointers of unknown type. An example is `posix_memalign()`, which returns an error value and sets the `void*` whose address you pass in to the allocated block of memory. There is basically no reason to ever use `void**` in C++, other than compatibility with these APIs.

Comment: Dereferencing `c` will throw an error: "'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type'".
In general, you can't dereference something into `void *` (note that you can still dereference void** as you did in `f1`, think of that as if the complier gives you a last chance to cast to a concrete type). You can still cast c to the desired pointer, and then dereference it.

Comment: There's almost *never* a reason to use a `void*` in C++. And this doesn't look like one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting from a `void*` back to a pointer of the original type is **not** undefined behavior:

```
int a = 10;

void* b = (void*)&a;

int* c = (int*)b;

int d = *c; //d == 10 now; this is fine
```

So, if `f2` cast `c` back to a `void**` before using it, the code would be well-defined. If `f2` tries to cast `c` to something else (for example, if f2 cast `c` to an `int*` even though it was given a `void**`), that *would* be undefined behavior.

Pretty much the only exception to this is casting to `char*`: that's guaranteed to be ok.

That being said, because you have no type safety when using `void*` pointers, if at all possible you should use something else.

This means that this:

```
void f2(void* c) {
    void** b = (void**)c;         // Get original void**
    void* b_value = *b;           // Dereference to get void*
    int* int_ptr = (int*)b_value; // Get int* pointer

    int value = *int_ptr;         // Use it
}
```

Is safe, **if and only if** `c` represents a pointer to a `void*` which itself is a `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code causes undefined behavior.

Below fragment is taken from `C11`from chapter §6.2.5:

> The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete
>   object type that cannot be completed.

This means that a pointer to void is an invalid operand for dereferencing.

Comment: OP is asking about C++, not C.