# Stack abstract data type C

Tags: c, void-pointers, abstraction

I'm trying to build and abstract lib for a stack in c, but i'm having some trouble defining the push function because of the variable void *data. How can i solve the push problem?

Is there a better way of creating an abstract lib with the same purpose?

```
typedef struct
{
    Data_Type data_type;
    size_t size;
    int top;
    void *data;

} Stack;


void push(Stack *stack, void *n)
{
    void *ptr = stack->data;
    *(ptr + stack->size * stack->top) = *n;
}
```

Comment: Which push problem?

Comment: @DevSolar im getting "error: incomplete type 'void' is not assignable" in the push function

Answer (score 3):

You cannot [dereference a void pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15468474/28128).  On the second line of your `push` function, you are derefencing a void pointer on both the left and right sides of the assignment.  I suggest you delete that line and instead use `memcpy` to copy the right number of bytes from `n` into your stack.