# assigning a void pointer to another

Tags: c, void-pointers

I am working on this method that should operate the insertion sort on a given array of unknown type

```
void binary_insertion_sort(void** array, size_t size, int (*compare)(void**,void**)){
  int i,j,destination;
  void* moving;
  for(i=1;i<(int)size;i++){
    j=i-1;
    moving=array[i];        
     //here I have serious doubts about this assignment
    destination=binary_search(array,moving,0,j,(*compare));
    while(j>=destination){
      swap(&array[j+1],&array[j]);
      j--;
    }
    array[j+1]=moving;      //here I have the same problem
  }  
}
```

I was thinking about doing something like memcpy() but I still don't know the size of the type.

Comment: @user17732522 corrected

Comment: even after that, not sure what you're asking. Sure, you can do `x1=x2`, that makes `x1` and `x2` point to the same thing... then what? You'll still need to know if it's an integer or a float or whatever, in order to do anything useful. [You can't dereference a void pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468441/dereference-void-pointer).

Comment: What do  you want to achieve? This sounds like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @user17732522 i'm reformulating the question, i'll update you. thanks anyway

Comment: It seems like you may be making the common mistake of failing to distinguish between the pointers themselves and the objects to which they point.  It is essential to learn this difference and keep it in mind.  To that end, what effect are you trying to achieve?  How would you recognize that you had achieved it?

Comment: It's exactly the same as writing `void assign(int x, int y) {x = y;}` but you write void* instead of int.  Does my version of assign work with ints? No, it doesn't. Why not?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I want to do a simple assignment between void* without knowing the type beforehand

Comment: Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/5so436KMG) what you're trying to do? No problems at all pointing `x1` or `x2` to strings, or assigning one to the other. The kicker is you need to know they're pointing to strings before you can do something like print them out.

Comment: @ramaswag, the type (of the pointers) is `void *`.  You ***do*** know it.  And you can assign any `void *` value to any `void *` object.  But it remains unclear whether that will achieve *the effect* you have in mind.

Comment: @ramaswag: Given a `void *`, it is impossible to assign the value of the thing it points to to another thing without knowing the type. That is because `void *` conveys no information about the object it points to, not even its size. It could be a one-byte `char`, a two-byte integer, an array of a million bytes, or something else. With just the pointer, the program does not know how many bytes to copy, let alone how the data in those bytes should be interpreted.

Comment: Assigning pointers doesn't copy the data that they point to.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I updated everything, maybe what I need to know it's clearer like this.

Comment: *"but I still don't know the size of the type."* - ever wonder why functions like `qsort` require *both* the sequence element count *and* the size of the element type within the sequence? I bet you're no longer wondering.

Comment: Why does the function presented attempt to work with type `void **`?  Compare with the signature of the standard [`qsort()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) function, which does essentially the same job.  Are you trying to sort an array of pointers to `void`, or an array of (other) objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort an array whose element type is unknown to you, then you should use the signature of the standard `qsort()` function, which does exactly the same job.  The signature presented in the question is similar, but not the same, and I see no good reason for the difference if the function's job is what you describe.

> I was thinking about doing something like memcpy() but I still don't know the size of the type.

No, you don't, *unless the the caller tells you*.  That information is not carried by type `void *` (nor type `void **`).  That's why the arguments to `qsort()` are, and those to your function should be,

- a pointer to the first element of the array (type `void *` would be the most appropriate for that)
- the number of elements in the array
- ***the size of the element type***
- a pointer to a comparison function that accepts pointers to array elements as arguments (again, `void *` is the most appropriate type for this).

---

HOWEVER, if the problem were slightly different, say "sort *an array of pointers to `void`* based on the order defined by a user-defined function that compares the objects to which the pointers point", then you don't need the size of the pointed-to objects, because you never need to move them.  You move only the pointers.  That might have this signature:

```
void binary_insertion_sort(void *array[], size_t nmemb, int (*compare)(void *, void *));
```

, which is equivalent to this:

```
void binary_insertion_sort(void **array, size_t nmemb, int (*compare)(void *, void *));
```

*Note the difference between this comparison function and your example*.  This describes a sort specifically of arrays of `void *`, where the sort order is user-defined and might depend on the pointed-to objects.  You don't need the size of the pointed to objects here, because what you're supposed to sort (and therefore swap) is the pointers:

```
void *p1, *p2;
// ...
void *tmp = p1;
p1 = p2;
p2 = tmp;
```

Comment: My reasoning behind this is:                                                                              
1)  if I need an object that is for example an int or a float, i should declare it void*   
2)  if I need an object that is a pointer to an int or a pointer to a float that would be void**
So if I need to compare or swap two addresses wouldn't they be void**?
Why am I wrong?

Comment: @ramaswag, I think you're missing *why* you pass a `void *` to the first array element to specify an array.  That's not a stand-in for `int` in the case of sorting an `int` array (for example).  Rather, it is a stand in for *pointer to `int`* a.k.a `int *`, which is what you would pass to a function that was specific to sorting arrays of `int`.

Comment: @ramaswag, as for the comparison function, it accepts pointers to the elements to compare.  The most natural type for a pointer that might point to an object of any type is `void *`.  Type `void **`, on the other hand, is specifically a pointer to an object whose type is exactly `void *`.

Comment: @ramaswag, again, the `qsort()` signature does the job you describe, and has done so very well for nearly half a century.  If you're still not getting it then I recommend working some exercises involving using `qsort()` to sort arrays.