# Is this deference of a void pointer correct?

Tags: c, pointers

I looked in google and stumbled upon this post, but this does not quite answer my question (or maybe it does I just could not reach there my self). [Dereference void pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468441/dereference-void-pointer)

I am trying to create a function that would set pointers of unknown types. Basically:

```
struct x{
type *links[LINK_SIZE];
// other data
};
somefunc(void *x, void *y void* z)
```

Here x is a pointer to struct x but passed as void pointer. I want to dereference the void * pointer to access its 1st element which is links. As far as I know all pointers in C are of equal size (Not sure! but at least with gcc compiler). So, In theory, it should work and it works with my gcc compiler. Basically if u dereference a pointer of a struct you get the 1st element in that struct. I was wondering if this is undefined behavior or not?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct e{
    struct e *links[2];
    int a;
}e;

void somefunc(void *x, void *y, void *z) {
    void **epl = (void **)x;
    epl[0] = y; 
// also see how I am accessing it like a normal array, is this even possible for void pointers?
    epl[1] = z;
}

int main(void) {
    e e1 = (e){{NULL, NULL}, 1};
    e e2 = (e){{NULL, NULL}, 2};
    e e3 = (e){{NULL, NULL}, 3};
    somefunc(&e1, &e2, &e3);    
    printf("%d\n", e1.links[0]->a);
    printf("%d\n", e1.links[1]->a);
    printf("%d\n", e1.a);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
The actual underlying problem is basically lets say I have 2 different structures.

```
typedef struct e{
    struct e *links[2];
    int a;
}e;

typedef struct f{
    struct f *links[2];
    float a;
}f;
```

I want 1 function that would be able to update the `links` for both the structs rather than having two functions one that cast to `f *` and other that cast to `e *`.

Comment: Your code in not correct. In the `somefunc` function `x` doesn't point to a pointer to something. So the initial cast to `void **` is invalid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do not understand can you please elaborate further? why it is not a pointer to a structure `e` ? I am passing `&e1` as argument. So, should it not be a pointer to `struct e`? For some reason it produces expected output, hence I am confused.

Comment: Yes `x` is a pointer to a structure, but it's not a pointer ***to a pointer*** to a structure.

Comment: Why aren't you casting the parameter `x` to `e *`?

Comment: What is your actual and underlying problem? If it's just plain curiosity, then that's all fine and okay, but please state so in the question itself. And include why you're wondering. Otherwise please ask about the underlying and actual problem directly (in the question itself).

Comment: Re "*is this even possible for void pointers?*", Yes, you can have arrays of void pointers. But you don't. The problem is `void **epl = (void **)x`. It should be `e *epl = (e *)x`.

Comment: Since the structs are both beginning with array of pointers, and pointers has the same size, the code is a bit tricky, but it should work. `x` can be casted to a pointer to an array of `void *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: You can't.

The longer answer is that it's possible to work around the problem and solve it in other ways.

One possible solution is to use a kind of inheritance, by using something called *the common initial sequence*, where both the structures use a common "base" structure as their first member.

Could be something like this:

```
typedef struct Base
{
    struct Base *links[2];
} Base;

typedef struct
{
    Base base;
    // Other e members here...
} e;

typedef struct
{
    Base base;
} f;
```

Now you can create an `e` object and pass a pointer to it with casting to the function:

```
void somefunc(Base *object)
{
    // Here you can use object->links[0] and object->links[1]
    // ...
}

int main(void)
{
    e e_object;

    somefunc((Base *) &e_object);
}
```

---

Another possibility is to use [*generic selection*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic):

```
#define somefunc(x)  _Generic((x), \
      e *: somefunc_e, \
      f *: somefunc_f) \
    (x)

int main(void)
{
    e e_object;
    f f_object;

    somefunc(&e_object);  // Will call somefunc_e(&e_object)
    somefunc(&f_object);  // Will call somefunc_f(&f_object)
}
```

While it will make the code using the structure seem more generic, you still need to implement the actual functions to handle the different structures.

So this adds more code, but it also makes it possible to do different things for the different types, which is harder with the "inheritance" code.

Comment: Thank you, I like your approach, you can debug it unlike macros. Could you also take the time to explain why my code produces the correct output when it should not?

Comment: Common initial sequence is about accessing the first member(s) of a struct through a pointer to a different struct with the same initial members, _given that a union containing both structs is present in the same translation unit_. That's not the case in your example. (See 6.5.2.3) What you are demonstrating is rather a different rule, namely that a pointer to the first member may be cast to/from a pointer to the struct (See 6.7.2.1).

Comment: I used the inheritance method after trying all options. inheritance seems the least amount of coding. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is undefined behavior because the C standard doesn't allow a pointer to one type to be converted to a pointer to another type and dereferenced except in a few specific cases.

In particular, while you can convert a pointer to a struct to a pointer to its first member (`e *` to `e *(*)[2]` in this case), you can't convert a `e *(*)[2]` to a `void **` and dereference because `e *[2]` and `void *` are not compatible types.  That they may have the same representation (which is why it appears to work) doesn't matter.

Assuming you have several structs with a similar structure, i.e.:

```
typedef struct e {
    struct e *links[2];
    int a;
} e;
typedef struct f {
    struct f *links[2];
    float a;
} f;
```

And you want one function to work with both of them, this might be a case for a function-like macro:

```
#define somefunc(x, y, z)\
  do {\
      (x).links[0] = (y);\
      (x).links[1] = (z);\
  } while (0)
```

Which you could call like this:

```
somefunc(e1, e2, e3);    
somefunc(f1, f2, f3);
```

Comment: I totally agree with you here, but could also explain why the code I shared produces correct output? should it even produce correct output?

Comment: @Pragmatic "Seems to work ok for now" is one of the many possible results when you have code with undefined behavior bugs. In some cases a certain compiler could even guarantee certain behavior in the form of a non-standard language extension, but I don't think that's the case here. More likely, the various forms of pointers in your example have the same underlying representation on the binary level so it works for that reason. But bugs may appear when the compiler makes conclusions about which variables that have been modified and which have not, using the rules known as "pointer aliasing".

Comment: @Lundin I looked into pointer aliasing it says that `int *`  pointer should not be aliased as `float *` and so on. But is that the case here? because I was told that `void *` or `char *` can hold any pointer. but you cannot do pointer arithmetic on `void *` and you can do it on `char *`. so any array of pointers should fit right into an array of void pointers, is that a correct assumption in compliance with C standard?

Comment: @Pragmatic A void pointer may be converted to/from any other object pointer. But that special rule does not apply to `void**`, which follows the same rules as any other normal pointer type. Additionally, the level of dereferencing must be consistent - you can't pass a `&e` (pointer to struct object) and wildly cast it to `void**` (pointer to pointer), that's just senseless.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I know all pointers in C are of equal size

C does not require all pointers are of equal size and use the same encoding.

*Object* pointers and *function* pointers of different sizes are not uncommon.

`struct` pointers all use the same size and encoding.  That size *may* differ from `void *`, yet that is uncommon.