# Runtime cast of void pointer

Tags: c, switch-statement, void-pointers

I'm writing a C program that applies a different type of quantization to an array depending on an environmental variable.

The problem is that, I need to use the same function `void foo(void* ptr, quant_t type, ...)` to do things on ptr, but I need to cast it beforehand to the correct type.

(quant_t is an enum type object)

I've tried to do

```
void foo(void* ptr, quant_t type, ...){
switch(type){
case UNIF:{
struct unif* my_ptr = (struct unif*) ptr;
break;
}
case KMEANS:{
struct kmeans* my_ptr = (struct kmeans*) ptr;
break;
}...}

my_ptr->a = bar(...);
my_ptr->b = baz(...);
}
```

But it does not work because the declaration of my_ptr is inside the scope of a switch case.

So I've tried to do something like this:

```
void foo(void* ptr, quant_t type, ...){
void* my_ptr = NULL;
switch(type){
case UNIF:{
my_ptr = (struct unif*) ptr;
break;
}
case KMEANS:{
my_ptr = (struct kmeans*) ptr;
break;
}...}

my_ptr->a = bar(...);
my_ptr->b = baz(...);
}
```

But it still does not work.

Comment: You apparently want `my_ptr->a = bar(...);` to operate on `my_ptr` with the type of `my_ptr` determined at run-time. C has no provision for that. There is no dynamic selection of type at run-time, with limited exception for the length of variable-length arrays. If `a` and `b` have fixed types, you can write code in the `switch` that prepares pointers to them based on the enumeration, and then you can use those pointers to assign values to them.

Comment: @Saverio Pasqualoni Instead of the switch statement use if-else statements to process defined pointers in blocks of the if-else statements.

Comment: Either `my_ptr` must always have the same type (e.g. a substruct within the `unif`/`kmeans` structures) and be declared before the `switch-statement or all operations must happen within the respective case statements.

Comment: Your switch statement simplifies to `void* my_ptr = ptr;`. No surprise it doesn't help.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78071797/589924) from yesterday

Comment: Write different versions of your function and use `_Generic` inside a macro to select the right one, based on the type of the first argument.

Comment: Do the return values of `bar(...)` and `baz(...)` depend on `type`? Could you call them and save the return values in local variables before the `switch (type)` statement?

Comment: If you have a set number of different types of pointers, consider a `union` of different pointers, not a `void` pointer. A pointer to a virtual table of all the different functions instead of a `switch` may be useful.

Comment: Put the usages inside the switch as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `->a` to work, the compiler must know the location (among other things) of the field relative to the pointer. This offset must be constant in C.

We can make this work by making your two types compatible with a third, and using that third type (`Base`).

```perl
typedef struct {
   A a;
   B b;
} Base;

typedef struct {
   Base base;
   …
} Unif;

typedef struct {
   Base base;
   …
} Kmeans;
```

```c
// `base` doesn't need to be the first field of `Unif` and `Kmeans`
// (unless you want to recuperate the orig ptr from a `Base *` at some point).

void foo( Base *ptr, … ) {
   ptr->a = bar( … );
   ptr->b = baz( … );
}

Unif *unif = …;
foo( &unif->base, … );

Kmeans *kmeans = …;
foo( &kmeans->base, … );
```

It's less safe, but we could also have called it as follows:

```c
// `base` must be the first field of `Unif` and `Kmeans`.

void foo( Base *ptr, … ) {
   ptr->a = bar( … );
   ptr->b = baz( … );
}

Unif *unif = …;
foo( (Base *)unif, … );

Kmeans *kmeans = …;
foo( (Base *)kmeans, … );
```

Which means we can make a few changes to reduce the code needed in the caller a little.

```c
// `base` must be the first field of `Unif` and `Kmeans`.

void foo( void *ptr_, … ) {
   Base *ptr = ptr_;
   ptr->a = bar( … );
   ptr->b = baz( … );
}

Unif *unif = …;
foo( unif, … );

Kmeans *kmeans = …;
foo( kmeans, … );
```

The last two are not as safe as the original as they defeat type checks through explicit and implicit casts.

Comment: @arfneto, Re "*And this would be an useful thing.*", Yes, yet completely irrelevant to the question. **It doesn't matter if the OP's function is variadic or not. The question isn't about that!** /// Re "*I would never imagine that the OP was not asking about what I just explained.*", Sorry, but I can't help you with this problem. I can only repeat my earlier advice:  There's a good chance you're wrong if you have to ignore all the text and half the code in the OP for your interpretation to make sense. /// When the mods delete your off-topic comments, it's not an invitation to repost them.

Comment: This is funny! **I deleted all the comments myself, sir**. It was going too long and boring and adding nothing to the topic or myself.

Answer (score -1):

> But it does not work because the declaration of my_ptr is inside the scope of a switch case.

It does not work, but not just because of the declaration of `my_ptr`. You can not just forward `...`

I will show an example that may or may not do what you want. I am not sure I understand what do you need.Anyway, if you want a dispacther based on a type and a pointer, this one may fit in.
If the functions uses the same type of arguments a simple 5-line VFT works, indexed by the type.

### Example

The basics

```
typedef enum
{
    UNIF,
    KMEANS
} Class_t;

typedef struct
{
    void        (*bar)(const char*, unsigned, ...);
} UNIF_t;

typedef struct
{
    void        (*baz)(const char*, unsigned, ...);
} KMEANS_t;

// the dispatcher
void     foo(Class_t type, void* ptr, unsigned N, ...);
```

#### `main` for this example

For testing:

- `UNIF_t` implements `bar`. The example `bar` here gets a string for id and (variadic) some `int` and just displays the values.
- `KMEANS_t` implements `baz`. The example `baz` here gets a string for id and (variadic) some `char*` and just displays the values.

```
int main(void)
{
    UNIF_t   unif   = {.bar=for_unif};
    KMEANS_t kmeans = {.baz=for_kmeans};

    void* p = &unif;
    foo(UNIF, p, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4);
    foo(KMEANS, &kmeans, 3, "Stack", "Overflow", "C");

    p = &kmeans;
    foo(KMEANS, p, 2, "What", "if?");
    foo(UNIF, &unif, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

The logic is trivial:

- a `struct` of each kind is created
- a pointer/type pair  is used to call the dispatcher `foo()`
- the dispatcher calls the required method

#### `foo()`

```
    void foo(Class_t type, void* ptr, unsigned N, ...)
    {
        va_list parms;
        va_start(parms, N);
        switch (type)
        {
            case UNIF:
            {
                ((UNIF_t*)ptr)->bar("testing for UNIF", N, parms);
                break;
            }
            case KMEANS:
            {
                ((KMEANS_t*)ptr)->baz("testing for KMEANS", N, parms);
                break;
            }
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Type 0x%X!\n", type);
                break;
        };  // switch()
        va_end(parms);
    }
```

This is sort of a `C++` *functor*. It is written this way here because I suppose that there is more data in the structs. If not a simple **VFT** indexed by the type works fine.

The only not common thing here is the building of a `va_list` for use in the inner functions.

#### output

```
UNIF: id is 'testing for UNIF', 4 args
        args: (1,2,3,4)

KMEANS: id is 'testing for KMEANS', 3 args
 1: 'Stack'
 2: 'Overflow'
 3: 'C'

KMEANS: id is 'testing for KMEANS', 2 args
 1: 'What'
 2: 'if?'

UNIF: id is 'testing for UNIF', 8 args
        args: (8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
```

#### full code of the example

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum
{
    UNIF,
    KMEANS
} Class_t;

typedef struct
{
    void (*bar)(const char*, unsigned, ...);
} UNIF_t;

typedef struct
{
    void (*baz)(const char*, unsigned, ...);
} KMEANS_t;

// the dispatcher
void foo(Class_t type, void* ptr, unsigned N, ...);

// functions for testing these 'classes'
void for_unif(const char*, unsigned N, va_list parms);
void for_kmeans(const char*, unsigned, va_list parms);

int main(void)
{
    UNIF_t   unif   = {.bar = for_unif};
    KMEANS_t kmeans = {.baz = for_kmeans};

    void* p = &unif;
    foo(UNIF, p, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4);
    foo(KMEANS, &kmeans, 3, "Stack", "Overflow", "C");

    p = &kmeans;
    foo(KMEANS, p, 2, "What", "if?");
    foo(UNIF, &unif, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);

    return 0;
}

void for_unif(const char* id, unsigned N, va_list parms)
{
    printf("\nUNIF: id is '%s', %d args\n\targs: (", id, N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N - 1; i += 1)
        printf("%d,", va_arg(parms, int));
    printf("%d)\n", va_arg(parms, int));
    return;
}

void for_kmeans(const char* id, unsigned N, va_list parms)
{
    printf("\nKMEANS: id is '%s', %d args\n", id, N);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        printf("%2u: '%s'\n", 1 + i, va_arg(parms, char*));
    return;
}

void foo(Class_t type, void* ptr, unsigned N, ...)
{
    va_list parms;
    va_start(parms, N);
    switch (type)
    {
        case UNIF:
        {
            ((UNIF_t*)ptr)
                ->bar("testing for UNIF", N, parms);
            break;
        }
        case KMEANS:
        {
            ((KMEANS_t*)ptr)
                ->baz("testing for KMEANS", N, parms);
            break;
        }
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Type 0x%X!\n", type);
            break;
    };  // switch()
    va_end(parms);
}
```

### more from the original question

```
void foo(void* ptr, quant_t type, ...){
void* my_ptr = NULL;
switch(type){
case UNIF:{
my_ptr = (struct unif*) ptr;
break;
}
case KMEANS:{
my_ptr = (struct kmeans*) ptr;
break;
}...}

my_ptr->a = bar(...);
my_ptr->b = baz(...);
}
```

if `my_ptr` is `void*` there is no meaning in  `my_ptr->a` or `my_ptr_b`.

Since `bar` and `baz` have the same signature, if all you can is in just use `my_ptr` to call a function inside `struct unif` or `struct kmeans`, based on type, it can even be simpler, a one-liner in fact:
`F[type](descr[type], N, parms);` using `foo` as below:

#### `foo()` as a one-liner

```
void foo(Class_t type, void* ptr, unsigned N, ...)
{
    va_list parms;
    va_start(parms, N);
    // clang-format off
    const char* descr[] = {
        [UNIF]= "type is UNIF",[KMEANS]= "type is KMEANS"};
        void(*F[])(const char* id, unsigned N, va_list parms) = {
        [UNIF]   = ((UNIF_t*)ptr)->bar,
        [KMEANS] = ((KMEANS_t*)ptr)->baz
    };
 
    F[type](descr[type], N, parms);
    va_end(parms);
}
```

If there are nothing else needed inside the `structs` and just the method is needed, It is a function table only, indexed by `type`: it works the same as the example above.

#### example 2

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum
{
    UNIF,
    KMEANS
} Class_t;

typedef struct
{
    void (*bar)(const char*, unsigned, ...);
} UNIF_t;

typedef struct
{
    void (*baz)(const char*, unsigned, ...);
} KMEANS_t;

// the dispatcher
void foo(Class_t type, void* ptr, unsigned N, ...);

// functions for testing these 'classes'
void for_unif(const char*, unsigned N, va_list parms);
void for_kmeans(const char*, unsigned, va_list parms);

int main(void)
{
    UNIF_t   unif   = {.bar = for_unif};
    KMEANS_t kmeans = {.baz = for_kmeans};

    void* p = &unif;
    foo(UNIF, p, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4);
    foo(KMEANS, &kmeans, 3, "Stack", "Overflow", "C");

    p = &kmeans;
    foo(KMEANS, p, 2, "What", "if?");
    foo(UNIF, &unif, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);

    return 0;
}

void for_unif(const char* id, unsigned N, va_list parms)
{
    printf("\nUNIF: id is '%s', %d args\n\targs: (", id, N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N - 1; i += 1)
        printf("%d,", va_arg(parms, int));
    printf("%d)\n", va_arg(parms, int));
    return;
}

void for_kmeans(const char* id, unsigned N, va_list parms)
{
    printf("\nKMEANS: id is '%s', %d args\n", id, N);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        printf("%2u: '%s'\n", 1 + i, va_arg(parms, char*));
    return;
}

void foo(Class_t type, void* ptr, unsigned N, ...)
{
    va_list parms;
    va_start(parms, N);
    // clang-format off
    const char* descr[] = {
        [UNIF]= "type is UNIF",[KMEANS]= "type is KMEANS"};
        void(*F[])(const char* id, unsigned N, va_list parms) = {
        [UNIF]   = ((UNIF_t*)ptr)->bar,
        [KMEANS] = ((KMEANS_t*)ptr)->baz
    };
    // clang-format on

    F[type](descr[type], N, parms);
    va_end(parms);
}
```

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78081529/runtime-cast-of-void-pointer

Comment: You appear to have gotten confused along the way, and you ended up answering a completely different question than the one asked. The OP wants to do `((UNIF_t*)ptr)->a = bar(); ((UNIF_t*)ptr)->b = baz();` or `((KMEANS_t*)ptr)->a = bar(); ((KMEANS_t*)ptr)->b = baz();` depending on the argument provided.  But you answered how to call `((UNIF_t*)ptr)->bar()` or `((KMEANS_t*)ptr)->baz()` depending on the argument. That's completely different.

Comment: I am not sure about that yet, but I believe that this is what the question asks for, lines like  `foo(UNIF, &unif, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);`. You see here `type`, pointer and a variadic function called upon inspecting the type **with the variadic parameters forwarded**. I included the complete source anyway code and the author can possibly tell us ...

Comment: Your code does not do `my_ptr->a = bar(...); my_ptr->b = baz(...);`, which the question is all about. You don't perform the assignments at all, and you call `foo` and `baz` conditionally instead of unconditionally.

Comment: Re "*and the assignment is there*", It would be wrong if you did it in main since it's something `foo` is supposed to do. But you don't. You don't assign to `a` and `b` in `main`. Or in `foo`. `a` and `b` don't even exist in your code.

Comment: The OP has spoken. Thew next time you have to ignore all the text in the OP and half the code in the OP for your interpretation to make sense, consider the possibility that you might have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Re "*do you read my post?*", Yes. It has nothing to do with the question. /// Re "*Not could you be also.*", No. There was no doubt. And the OP has since confirmed. /// Re "*What is `my_ptr->a` in the original post? What is `a`?*",  A field both `UNIF_t` and `KMEANS_t` has. /// Re "*Did you noticed that my_ptr is void*?*", Of course! That's why the code doesn't work. /// Again, the OP has since "told us". You said that would end it. Why are you continuing?

Comment: @ikegami how did the OP spoke? He told in person you what `a` and `b` are? So  you could write an answer that is not even close not close to compile? OK then. My mistake.

Comment: Re "*how did the OP spoke?*", By upvoting and approving an answer. /// Re "*He told in person you what a and b are?*", No, that's in the question.