# variable number of arguments in C

Tags: c

I got a problem with variable number of arguments. I'm pretty bad in C. In my task i need to specify the types in undeclared parameters. It seems i don't have a reason to do it, because i'm using just a string, but i need to use it with <stdarg.h>. The function suppose to print words which have the specific letter repeating 3+ times. So, when I'm trying this code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void repeatingLetter(char* sentence, char letter) 
{
    char* word = strtok(sentence, " ");

    while (word != NULL) {
        int count = 0;
        int len = strlen(word);

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (word[i] == letter) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count >= 3) {
            printf("%s\n", word);
        }

        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}

void findWords(int numSentences, ...) 
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, numSentences);

    char letter;
    printf("Enter a letter to check: ");
    scanf("%c", &letter);

    for (int i = 0; i < numSentences; i++)
    {
        char* sentence = va_arg(args, char*);

        printf("Words in '%s' with '%c' repeated 3 or more times:\n", sentence, letter);
        repeatingLetter(sentence, letter);
        printf("\n");
    }

    va_end(args);
}

int main() 
{
    int numSentences;
    printf("Enter a number of sentences: ");
    scanf("%d", &numSentences);
    getchar(); 

    char** sentences = (char**)malloc(numSentences * sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i < numSentences; i++)
    {
        sentences[i] = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
        printf("Enter a sentences %d: ", i + 1);
        fgets(sentences[i], 100, stdin);
        sentences[i][strcspn(sentences[i], "\n")] = '\0';
    }

    findWords(numSentences, sentences);

    for (int i = 0; i < numSentences; i++) 
    {
        free(sentences[i]);
    }
    free(sentences);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting something like that:

```
    Enter a number of sentences: 3
    Enter a sentences 1: Hello world
    Enter a sentences 2: oooooops
    Enter a sentences 3: gdsgdgdg
    Enter a letter to check: o
    Words in '╨Ъ.┌c' with 'o' repeated 3 or more times:
    
    Words in '╨Ъ.┌c' with 'o' repeated 3 or more times:
    
    Words in 'o
    
    gdgdg
    
    d
    
    ' with 'o' repeated 3 or more times:
```

I don't understand what's a problem. Can you please help me?

I have tried to do this with integer and float. There weren't any problems, but I can't understand what's wrong with strings

Comment: *"It seems i don't have a reason to do it"* Correct.  You're calling with two arguments, so declare the function to take two arguments.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Include the output in your question as text, formatted as code.

Comment: Aside: please don't mix the use of `scanf()` and `fgets()` and `getchar()` to kludge your way out of trouble. Use one method. As for `scanf("%c", &letter);` you might need to add a space as `scanf(" %c", &letter);`. But it's better just to use `fgets()` for all user input and extract what you need from the string. During development, echo the inputs you think you got back to the user.

Comment: Why do you expect to have the sentences passed as argument one by one? You supply to the function a pointer to an array of pointers to `char`, and you will get a single argument: a pointer to an array of pointers to `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my task i need to specify the types in undeclared parameters. It seems i don't have a reason to do it, because i'm using just a string, but i need to use it with <stdarg.h>. The function suppose to print words which have the specific letter repeating 3+ times

These parameters are not *"undeclared"* . `...` is the declaration, a placeholder for a variable number of arguments. This is what `stdargs` is all about.

And there is a function that will get these parameters, all strings as you said, and print all that have some letter occurring at least `n` times.

The probable target of your program is to call the function from a *variadic function* with a variable number of arguments. If it is not you objective please post the task requirements.

### it is easier to solve one problem each time

Complete code is at the end for this example

#### 1 of 2: the function

```
void repeatingLetter(char* sentence, char letter)
{
    char* word = strtok(sentence, " ");

    while (word != NULL)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int len   = strlen(word);

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (word[i] == letter) { count++; }
        }

        if (count >= 3) { printf("%s\n", word); }

        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

**About the original code**

- do not `printf()` things inside the target function.
- do not return `void`
- the function scans a word, not a sentence
- do not write interactive code. It only slows down everything

In `C` `0` is `false`. Only `0`. Return `false` for a string not matching the criteria. Just that. If you have a sentence, break that into words and then call the function with the words...

#### Example

```
int repeatingLetter(
  const char* word, const char letter, size_t times)
{
  if (word == NULL) return 0;
  if ((letter == 0) && (times == 0)) return 0;
  char*  pl = (char*)word;  // pointer to 1st letter
  size_t count = 0;
  while (*pl != 0)
  {
      if (*pl == letter)
          if (++count == times) return 1;
      ++pl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This one does just that, but no more than that. Returns `1` if `letter` appears at least `times` times in the `word`.

To test it you can just write another function in advance, like this

```
int t_repeat(const char* s, const char letter, size_t times)
{
    printf("\n\
    sentence: \"%s\"\n\
    letter: '%c'\n\
    total number of times: %llu\n",
        s, letter, times);
    int res = repeatingLetter(s, letter, times);
    printf("\n\tfunction returned %d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

it is trivial, but can save some time if you do this before. See this code for `main()`:

```
int main(void)
{
    t_repeat("aaa", 'a', 3);
    t_repeat("aa", 'a', 3);
    t_repeat("aaa", 'a', 4);
    t_repeat("aaa", 0, 4);
    t_repeat("aaa", 'a', 0);
    t_repeat(NULL, 'a', 0);
    return 0;
}
```

So it is easy to type some conditions and test it, before even considering the rest of the program.

**ouptut for this test**

```
    sentence: "aaa"
    letter: 'a'
    total number of times: 3

        function returned 1

    sentence: "aa"
    letter: 'a'
    total number of times: 3

        function returned 0

    sentence: "aaa"
    letter: 'a'
    total number of times: 4

        function returned 0

    sentence: "aaa"
    letter: ''
    total number of times: 4

        function returned 0

    sentence: "aaa"
    letter: 'a'
    total number of times: 0

        function returned 0

    sentence: "(null)"
    letter: 'a'
    total number of times: 0

        function returned 0
```

So it seems to be ok to go on

#### 2 of 2: calling the function with a variable number of strings

If `findWords` is

```
void findWords(
    const char letter,
    const size_t n_times,
    const size_t N, ...)
```

then `main()` for a test could be as simple as

```
int main(void)
{
    findWords('x', 3, 8,
        "xvalue",
        "xvaluexx",
        "xxxAll",
        "Sxtxaxck",
        "Sxtxaxck",
        "Stack Overflow",
        "xOverflowx",
        "xOverflowxx"
    );
    return 0;
};  // main()
```

**output of such test**

```
"xvaluexx"
"xxxAll"
"Sxtxaxck"
"Sxtxaxck"
"xOverflowxx"
```

Here is a simple implementation for `findWords`:

```
// find 'l' at least 't' times in each of the 
// 'N' arguments in '...'
void findWords(
    const char l, const size_t t, const size_t N, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        char* string = va_arg(args, char*);
        if (repeatingLetter(string, l, t) != 0)
            printf("\"%s\"\n",string);
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```

And is almost the same function as `t_repeat()` in the first test.

#### complete code for the example

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int  repeatingLetter(const char*, const char, size_t);
void findWords(const char, const size_t, const size_t, ...);

int main(void)
{
    findWords('x', 3, 8,
        "xvalue",
        "xvaluexx",
        "xxxAll",
        "Sxtxaxck",
        "Sxtxaxck",
        "Stack Overflow",
        "xOverflowx",
        "xOverflowxx"
    );
    return 0;
};  // main()

int repeatingLetter(
    const char* word, const char letter, size_t times)
{
    if (word == NULL) return 0;
    if ((letter == 0) && (times == 0)) return 0;
    char*  pl    = (char*)word;  // pointer to 1st letter
    size_t count = 0;
    while (*pl != 0)
    {
        if (*pl == letter)
            if (++count == times) return 1;
        ++pl;
    }
    return 0;
}

// find 'l' at least 't' times in each of the 
// 'N' arguments in '...'
void findWords(
    const char l, const size_t t, const size_t N, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        char* string = va_arg(args, char*);
        if (repeatingLetter(string, l, t) != 0)
            printf("\"%s\"\n",string);
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```

### on the creation of a `va_list`

When you declare a function like

```
void findWords(
    const char l, const size_t t, const size_t N, ...)
```

the compiler gets aware of the variadic nature of the function. Then, when a call is made like in

```
int main(void)
{
    findWords('x', 3, 8,
        "xvalue",
        "xvaluexx",
        "xxxAll",
        "Sxtxaxck",
        "Sxtxaxck",
        "Stack Overflow",
        "xOverflowx",
        "xOverflowxx"
    );
    return 0;
};  // main()
```

code is inserted to build the `va_list` for this call and pass it down to `findWords`. Here the number of arguments is a fixed number. `main` is not a *variadic function*. `findWords()` is variadic, and the `va_list` it gets can be even forwarded to inner functions.

If you need to build such a thing at runtime you can use a custom `struct`, or a simple `NULL`-terminated `void*` array. But you will not use `stdargs.h`. If you do that you can even mix the argument types or pass down a list of type/value pairs.

#### `main(int argc,char* argv[]` gets a variable number of arguments

In fact once the program is loaded the number of arguments is fixed: the OS builds the `argv` array and sets up `argc`.

Comment: Wow, nice explanation. Thanks man) But is there a way to pass all inputs as arguments to a function? (this means the user types all the lines)

Comment: No. There is no way, AFAIK. This is not the idea of `va_list` as in `stdargs.h`. The `...` thing is prepared by the compiler, like in a call to `printf`. But you can easily build such dynamic thing, a common way being to use a NULL-terminated array of pointers, like `void**`. I will edit my answer with some comments

Comment: See _"on the creation of a va_list"_ on the answer for comments on building such thing at runtime.

Comment: Oh, I finally got how it actually works. I've just never used it before and I'm new to C. Thank you very much, you were a big help)

Comment: at https://stackoverflow.com/a/78084297/11234199 I posted a program that forwards a `va_list` to an inner function and calls a _variadic function_ using different types of arguments. You can find it helpful. Or not :) since it was marked for deletion and downvoted in minutes when posted :D

Answer (score 1):

There is *not* a variable number of arguments here. There are two: you are providing the function with a count, and a pointer through which you can access a bunch of memory that you've allocated to hold string data.

To make it work as currently being invoked from `main`, the minimal fix for your `findWords` function is this:

```
void findWords(int numSentences, char** sentences) 
{
    char letter;
    printf("Enter a letter to check: ");
    scanf("%c", &letter);

    for (int i = 0; i < numSentences; i++)
    {
        char* sentence = sentences[i];

        printf("Words in '%s' with '%c' repeated 3 or more times:\n", sentence, letter);
        repeatingLetter(sentence, letter);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The whole point of variable arguments is when you have a function that can be called with, well... *a variable number of arguments*. Examples you'll be familiar with already are `printf` and `scanf`. Those can both receive one or more arguments, and the actual number of arguments you should provide is determined by the first argument.

You don't need that. You've confused "variable arguments" with "variable number of elements". All you needed to do was tell your function how many sentences there are and where to find them.